# How to safely generate 200V from low voltage supply

Tags: voltage-regulator, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

Unfortunately, this post requires quite a bit of background if it's going to be useful to anybody (including me).

I have been trying to build a relatively high voltage power converter for part of my grad project, and can't seem to get reality to match theory. I have a 12V supply and need to step it up to 200V so that I can drive some electrostatically driven MEMS devices. I have been trying to, as much as possible, make the topology compliant with relevant electrical safety standard (IEC60601-1 is the specific standard, but the concepts are essentially the same as in IEC60950).

From the safety standard, I determined I need to isolate the high voltage circuit from the low voltage circuit (power a computer and other simple LV electronics). The application calls for a high voltage rail (that runs some HV op-amps) and bi-polar low voltage rails (for low voltage op amps).

Conservative Power requirements:

- Isolated 200V rail, 4W
- Isolated ~10V rail, 2W (no tight voltage regulation required)
- Isolated ~-10V rail, 2W (no tight voltage regulation required)

So a conservative max of 8W total draw, which I would think isn't too hard to pull off.

I have designed the circuit around the LT3748 switching controller, which is designed to work in a flyback converter. It uses primary side sensing during the flyback period to sample the output voltage from the primary side and regulates that voltage, without needing to bridge the magnetic isolation of the transformer. This is helpful for safety because the fewer components bridging the isolation barrier, the better. This is the basic flyback circuit.

[image: Basic Flyback converter]

And I have modified this circuit to have 3 separate output windings. One for the high voltage, and two for the low voltages. Because I could not find a suitable transformer off-the-shelf, I ended up winding my own transformer on a toroidal core. I have read that, typically, flyback converter transformer cores are gapped, but all of my theory digging has lead me to believe that it only improves temperature stability and linearity (save that argument for another time :) ).

**Transformer Design**

- Primary inductance = 10uH (2 turns on the core I am using)
- Turns ratio to high voltage winding = 20:1
- Turns ratio to low voltage windings = 1:1

I have measured the inductances of the individual windings on an impedance analyzer and they are what they should be. I expect this circuit to operate at 100kHz when fully loaded with a duty cycle around 50%. I have appropriately designed in high breakdown voltage components for the FET and the output diode.

**The problem**
At least the apparent problem : This circuit behaves quite as expected when only the low voltage windings are installed. When the high voltage winding is added, things get funny. The expected behavior for a flyback is such that, when the primary FET turns on, the voltage on the high side of the diode is supposed to quickly shoot to a large negative voltage (-Vin*turns ratio). Then, when the FET turns off, the voltage at the low side of the primary is supposed to shoot up to the flyback voltage very quickly (Vin+Vout/turns ratio).

In reality, I am getting ~250ns delays between the switch action and the expected voltage changes. The circuit does produce a large positive voltage, but it majorly over-regulates, and basically every cycle is actually limited by the current trip voltage on the low side of the FET. So it's switching and generating voltage, so I believe it's all wired up correctly, it's just not behaving due to parasitics. I have suspicion that there is excessive capacitance on the high voltage secondary that reflects to the primary differently during different phases of the cycle. Additionally, this circuit is supposed to detect the end of the secondary current cycle by waiting for the flyback voltage to drop below Vin signaling it's time to turn the primary back on, but the rate of slew of the flyback voltage seems very slow and perhaps the cause of the trouble.

I could start posting oscilloscope traces, but perhaps I will save that for questions that hopefully arise.

**The first Question**
I suspect my issue here is too much capacitance, and possibly some exacerbation by the high turns ratio of the transformer. I can't even scope probe the secondary terminals without altering the behavior of the circuit, so I think it's super sensitive to capacitance on the secondary. What parasitics are likely to cause slow voltage slewing and delays of behavior in this type of circuit? I expect the circuit to operate at 100kHz with  50% duty, but the ferrite core is only permeable up to 2MHz. And once you wind on the windings, the stray capacitance make the transformer self-resonant at some frequency below 2MHz. For this circuit to work, how much capacitance do you suppose you can tolerate on/between windings?

**The Second Question**
If I needed to come up with an interim solution for this that was demonstrably safe, how might I got about doing it? I personally am driven to understand the problem, but practically I also need an alternate solution ASAP.

I would greatly appreciate any advice the community can offer!

Comment: Have you tried the various output windings, separately?

Comment: No, a gapped core is essential for flybacks, at least for powers at the watts level, otherwise you end up with far too oversized core, and so parasitics far too high, which seems to be one of your problems. If you don't know why you need a gapped core, you're not ready to design a flyback.

Comment: I'm suspecting inter-winding capacitance.  Post a picture of your output transformer?  Maybe do some measurements with a signal generator?

Comment: @Neil_UK: He's a student.  He's not ready to design anything.  That's what this project is for -- to provide him with blocks to stumble over, so that he can learn.

Comment: I can believe that I have overlooked something crucial about the core. My logic on the flyback transformer was this... the design equations for flybacks ends up requiring a particular primary inductance, and a peak primary current. Together those define a peak flux. Therefore, I need a core with enough area not to saturate at maximum flux density. That's how I picked my core.

Comment: To continue, if ungapped I need only a few turns to get the necessary inductance. If I do gap it, I need more turns to get same inductance. Either way, I need the same inductance and the same peak current, so the same peak flux, so the same flux density regardless of if there is a gap or not.

Comment: @TimWescott My transformer is 20 turns evenly spaced around circumference in a single layer. Then I wrapped that layer in some teflon tape and did my low voltage windings over top of those. I used this core [link](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/epcos-tdk/B64290L0674X087/495-5086-ND/3913587)

Comment: I can't remember the materials-science detail of why you need the gap.  But I do remember that I once ran the numbers, and found that the majority of the energy stored by the coil right before you cut the current is in the gap.  The basic design of the flyback circuit is that the source charges up the inductor, then the inductor discharges into the load -- so unlike other topologies, the inductor **must** be able to store a chunk of energy.

Comment: @TimWescott, I ran into this exact issue. Energy stored is .5*L*I^2. If I have the same L and the same I... stored energy should be the same.

Comment: @Neil_UK , you can probably poke holes in my arguments. In my mind, if I gap, then wind more turns, that can only lead to more leakage inductance and more capacitance.

Comment: @deltamac your flux argument is total pants. If gapping reduces the permeability to (say) one quarter then to retrieve the inductance you double the turns. The net effect is that with the gapped core and double the turns, the flux density is halved. Reason: permeability has quartered, turns have doubled, flux is therefore half. Inductance is proportional to turns squared in case you didn’t know.

Comment: If you have wound 20 turns on a core that is a 3000 nH per turn squared, the inductance you have wound is 1.2 mH and not what you think.

Comment: @Andyaka, the secondary in 40 turns on a 2.88uH/T^2 core. I expected 4.6mH on the high voltage winding.  LIkewise, the primary is 2 turns and gives, 11.5uH which is what I measure. Is this wrong for some reason I am not seeing?

Comment: Higher up you said your transformer was 20 turns. But you will need a gap.

Comment: @Andyaka, I think you just clarified one major thing I was missing. I think I have been using the formulae for **flux linkage**, not *flux*. Flux linkage (N * flux) is the same in both cases, but flux is reduced with increased turns and same inductance.

Comment: @Andyaka, the turns ratio is 20:1, the primary has 2 turns and the secondary has 40. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @deltamac For a given power throughput W at a given frequency f, you need x=W/f joules stored in the magnetic field. Your core will have a given max flux before saturation Bmax. Calculate what weight of core you need to store x joules with a gap, and without a gap, and compare (hint,energy goes as H*B, Bmax is fixed, you can increase H by gapping). Only then start thinking about turns and current.

Comment: Aim for no more than 0.3 Tesla for Bmax is my advice. What peak current did you calculate for peak energy transfer. What switching frequency also? What is the mean circumference of the toroid and what permeability has it got. That tells you everything plus what Neil said.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's my take just to double-check things: -

- Your primary inductance is 11.76 uH formed from two turns on a core of \$A_L\$ = 2940 nH/turn\$^2\$.
- With 12 volts applied (charge cycle) current rises at V/L = 1.02 amps per microsecond
- Your operating frequency and duty are aiming to be 100 kHz at 50% hence the charge time is 5 microseconds
- In that time, the current reaches a peak of about 5.1 amps
- The stored energy is \$\frac{LI^2}{2}\$ = 153 micro joules
- At 100 kHz, this is an power throughput of 15 watts.

All seems OK because duty can be turned down a bit to accomodate lower powers. If 8 watts is the max power then you only need to transfer 8 uJ per cycle and this means a peak current of 3.7 amps and a therefore a duty of about 36%.

But, with an ungapped core, what is the H-field? H-field is ampere turns per metre where the "per metre" part is the mean circumference of the core (90 mm or thereabouts in the data sheet). The H-field level that liberates 8 watts is 3.7 amps x 2 turns divided by 0.09 metres = 82 At/m.

The core (N87) relative permeability is 2200 so multiplying this by 82 and the permeability of free space (\$4\pi\times 10^{-7}\$) means a flux density of 0.227 teslas and this is fine in my book but not a lot of clearance before saturation. You will be strongly saturating at a 50% duty cycle.

But, your load must consume that 8 watts or the core will, what is known as, walk into saturation. In other words, if you are using a fixed duty cycle you must dissipate that power in your load.

If your load doesn't dissipate the power, the output voltage will continue to rise until that power is consumed but, more than likely you will hit core saturation before that point: -

> The circuit does produce a large positive voltage, but it majorly
>   over-regulates, and basically every cycle is actually limited by the
>   current trip voltage on the low side of the FET

Sounds to me like you need to control the duty cycle better. Maybe the chip you proposed isn't working as you thought it might. Try adding a load just in case.

I also note that you are not implementing a flyback catch circuit as per figure 18 in the data sheet: -

[image]

Given the application and the amount of leakage flux in a high step-up transformer you should use one. The design above is 5 watts and not a million miles different from your application. Please justify not using a flyback catch circuit to prevent damage to the MOSFET.

Also noteworthy is that the primary inductance in the design above (also for a 12 volt supply) is 100 uH and herein might lie another problem; the LT3748 relies on regulating the output voltage by using the back-enf during flyback and it seems to rely on a certain amount of leakage inductance for correct operation. I'm not an expert in this family of chips so I would recommend further reading to see if your primary inductance is suitable at 100 kHz. It might be necessary to wind more primary inductance and operate at a higher duty cycle.

[Here's](http://www.stades.co.uk/#Ferrites) a link to a website that takes you through an example of designing a ferrite core and considerations for gapping. And [here's](http://www.stades.co.uk/Flyback/flyback%20DCM2.html) another part of that site that discusses flyback operation and later on discusses the use of the ferrite core previously mentioned.

Comment: This is exactly my calculations, and the reasoning behind thinking it is ok not to use a gapped transformer.

Comment: I actually do have snubber circuits designed and installed, and they seem to be doing a good job of damping the ringing due to leakage.

Comment: The thing that sticks out is that my turns ratio is probably higher than it has to be. Maybe I can turn that back and maybe reduce the parasitic. Is there a particular winding pattern I should use to minimize them?

Comment: The other strange thing is that relates to your walk up comment. It limits below the nominal duty cycle on a current limit, and somehow outputs TOO much voltage.

Comment: You must have a load connected that is close to what the maximum is. Did you have a load? You were right about the calculations for not gapping it. I'm so used to gapping flybacks that I really did think you'd screwed up in this area especially how you didn't understand the main reason behind it. Is it operating at 100 kHz and at what duty into what load with what output voltage (and input voltage)?

Comment: Good news! I think this is almost working! I re-wound the transformer with a slightly higher primary inductance (3 turns) and a lower turns ratio (1:10). It regulates correctly to 200V with light loads and the crazy sensitive to capacitance is gone. It’s now under-volting on a current trip at 2A. I think I can adjust and make this work. It also now drives all three secondaries simultaneously.

Comment: If this does work... I’m not actually sure what the problem would have been. Does a large turns ratio exacerbate parasitic capacitance somehow? I still have 30 turns on the secondary...

Comment: There’s always parasitic capacitance from the mosfet that drives the primary and this is usually the dominator, usually several times higher than reflected capacitance from the secondary. I’m struggling to see that it is capacitance.

Comment: I have this basically working, now. 25uH primary (3 turns). 30 turns to HV winding, 2 turns on the LV windings. My primary side snubber is a 1n +20R and runs just  a little warm. The secondary snubber I can't actually get to work. Any reasonable values I try make it oscillate and you can hear the cermic caps pulsing like crazy. I have just left them off as it appears to work reasonably well despit the poor damping on the secondary ring.

Comment: You shouldn't need a secondary snubber - maybe you can reveal what you tried? Anything that tries to clamp the negative voltage on the secondary side is going to be problematic. Good news about getting it to work though.